# How to reload ajax without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to update a simple_form when the focus is out. I did this but I can only do it only once and i cannot find out how to make it apply to all the input form. 
here's my code :

```
<%= content_for :after_js do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'autocomplete-rails-custom' %>
<script>
var autocomplete_field = $('#user_job_name')

autocomplete_field.on('focus', function(){
  console.log('focus')
  var search = 'A'
  if (autocomplete_field.val() && autocomplete_field.val().length > 0) {
    search = autocomplete_field.val()
  }
  autocomplete_field.autocomplete( 'search', search )
})
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input').blur(function() {
    $('#refresh').trigger('submit.rails');
  });
});
</script>
<% end %>
```

And the HTML from the simple_form :

```
  <%= simple_form_for user, remote: true, html: {class: 'full-width ', id: "refresh"} do |f| %>
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="admin">
```

With input like this :

```
<td class='float-label'>
 <%= f.input :first_name
   label: false %>
</td>
```

'input' refers to the input form and #refresh is an ID I assign to the simple_form.

So I think the ajax function do not refresh and I have no clue of how to do it...

A little help would be appreciate :)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `$('input').blur(function() {
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:$('#refresh').attr("action"),
        data:$('#refresh').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);

        }
    });
});`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. However, I have all the log in my console so I guess you were pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

If you use simple_form with remote true, try this:

```
$('input').blur(function() {
  $('#refresh').trigger('submit.rails');
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I do use remote true, but still not working.

Comment: @RaphaëlFOSSE Have you check the log, is there any request sent ?
If not yet, we can debug by console.log("inside the blur callback function!") to make sure the action triggered. :)

Comment: Yup, the action is triggered, i have 'response post users'. I just can do it as many time as I want without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer but only by using javascript, which is not really what I was looking for, but here it is :

```
 var form = document.getElementById("refresh");

 form.addEventListener("focus", function( event ) {
 event.target.style.background = "pink";
 }, true);

form.addEventListener("focusout", function( event ) {
$('#refresh').trigger('submit.rails');
}, true);
```

Even if it is working, It seems that the entire form is reload every time it lost focus on an input.